# (Doob-Dynkin Theorem) Sigma algebra generated by a function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,F)$ a measurable space. Let $f\in M(X,F)$. Consider the sigma algebra generated by a function $\sigma(f):={f^{-1}(B):B\in \textit{B}(\mathbb{R})}$, where $\textit{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Borel sigma algebra.

Show that if $\phi\in M(X,\sigma(f))$, then exists a borel measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi =g\circ f$.

I don't know how to start. I thought that a good idea could be to prove it for simple measurable functions, but I can figure out how to do it.

I'll appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea to deal with simple functions is good.

Assume that $\phi$ is the characteristic function of an element of $\sigma(f)$, say $A$. Then we choose $g$ as the characteristic function of $f^{-1}(A)$. If $\phi$ is a linear combination with non-negative coefficients of such sets, the idea is the same. If $\phi$ is non-negative, then there is a sequence $(\phi_k)$ of simple non-negative functions such that $\phi_k(x)\uparrow \phi(x)$ for all $x$. For each $\phi_k$, there is a function $g_k$ such that $\phi_k=g_k\circ f$. Furthermore, the sequence $(g_k)_k$ is non-decreasing, hence it converges to a function $g$ (that why we dealt with the case $\phi$ non-negative separately).

This is Doob-Dynkin's theorem.

Comment: In "Probability Theory" by  Achim Klenke presents this simply as "Factorization lemma" without any reference to Doob or Dynkin, and the wikipedia article does not clarify why it is called like that, do you know any reason why is this? when did this lemma first appeared with the name you present? (Sadly I have no access right now to the two books references in wiki)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi$ is the limit of a sequence of simple functions $\phi_k$ which you already expressed as $\phi_k = g_k \circ f$ for some Borel measurable $g_k: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

If $g_k$ converges everywhere on $\mathbb R$, then we are done (by letting $g := \lim g_k$), but sadly we only know that $g_k$ converges on $f(X)$.

If $f(X)$ is measurable, then we are done, but there is no guarantee that $f(X)$ is always measurable.

But fortunately, there is a measurable $E$ such that $f(X) \subset E$ and that $g_k$ converges on $E$. Can you define $E$ to complete the proof?